# If I use HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, duplicates

I use `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>` in Java.

When input value is comes,

For example, input value is `[1, "stack"]`, `[2, "over"]`, `[1, "flow"]`.....

I want to enter value `[1, ["stack", "flow"]]`, `[2, "over"]` in HashMap.

But key value is duplicate. So, HashMap was overwrite.

So, What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a [Guava Multimap](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap):

> The traditional way to represent a graph in Java is `Map<V, Set<V>>`, which is awkward in a number of ways. Guava's Multimap framework makes it easy to handle a mapping from keys to multiple values.
>
> A `ListMultimap` will map keys to a `List` of values, keeping track of their order, while a `SetMultimap` will map keys to a `Set` of distinct values.

Comment: Oh.. Thanks for you. I will use Guava!

Answer (score 1):

Call `get` on the `Map`. If it returns a `List` (`Set` may be more appropriate) add to that. If it returns `null`, create a collection, add the value, put it in the map.

Better, use some third-party multimap.